# SQL Server Reporting Services Charts, How display more than 6 rows of cat name

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

First at all thanks for reading.

I have a problem in SQL Server Reporting Services with the chats. I am using bar char and I split the info by category = cat_name, then i want to split the bars for the value of that cat_name

Example:

- Category group = cat_name
- Value = cat_value

So the bar chart displays the info but it just shows 6 rows with the labels the others just show the bar with the value but not the name of the category.

I assumed that the bar chart has 6 rows to display name as default but anyone knows how to increase it as many as categories I have ??

I have many categories with value and the data is fine but I need to display the name of each category too :( and the report just shows me 6.

I can't post pic cause I don't have enough reputation

Comment: How many categories will you expect to have at most?

Answer (score 0):

If all your data is showing (just not all the labels), then that seems to be discussed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239363%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) under "Displaying all Labels on the Category Axis". It suggests you do the following:

1. Right-click on the Category axis
2. Select Axis Properties
3. Under the Axis Options tab, change Interval to 1.

If the interval is set to Auto, it will select the best interval to show 6 or fewer labels. More details on this [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239317%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

If not all of your data is showing, then make sure, under the Labels tab of the Axis Properties dialog, that Auto-Fit is disabled.